# Pointcut matching types with certain parent class

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Is it possible in Spring AOP to implement a pointcut that matches types with a certain parent class?

I'd like to do it with the `@AfterReturning` annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AspectJ you can use `some.package.ParentClass+` to represent "all classes that extend `some.package.ParentClass`".

Comment: `some.package.ParentClass+.*` works. See http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-29716.html

Comment: @NewTalk Yes you'll want `some.package.ParentClass+.*` if you want to mach **methods/fields of any class that extends ParentClass**.